Having some issues with Google Calendar redirect in my app. Any help is appreciated
I'm making a Web app as part of a Capstone project. I decided to use the Google Calendar API with JavaScript, not realizing how complex Google's APIs are. Add that to the fact that I'm having to rush through it due to lost time, meaning that I've missed a lot of details.
What I am trying to do is have the Google sign-in popup appear upon clicking a button on my calendar page, and have the calendar appear on the page once a user has signed in.
Here's the code in question. First is the main config code:
(google-cal-config.js)

const CLIENT_ID = require("./config");
const API_KEY = require("./config");

const DISCOVERY_DOC =
  "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest";

const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
];

const content = document.getElementById("content");

const sidebarHeading = document.getElementById("sidebar-heading");
const signInBtn = document.getElementById("authorize_button");
const signOutBtn = document.getElementById("signout_button");
const upcomingSearch = document.getElementById("upcoming-search");
const upcommingSearchBtn = document.getElementById("upcoming-search-btn");

let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;

const apiConfig = document.getElementById("api-config");
const clientConfig = document.getElementById("client-config");

function maybeEnableButtons() {
  if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    signInBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

async function initializeGapiClient() {
  await gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
  });
  gapiInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

function gapiLoaded() {
  gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient);
}

function gisLoaded() {
  tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: "",
  });
  gisInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

function handleAuthClick() {
  console.log("Sign In button clicked");
  try {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
      if (resp.error !== undefined) {
        console.error("Auth Error: ", resp.error);
        throw resp;
      }
      sidebarHeading.style.visibility = "collapse";
      signOutBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
      signInBtn.innerText = "Refresh";
      upcommingSearch.style.visibility = "visible";
      await listUpcomingEvents();
    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" });
    } else {
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during handleAuthClick: ", error);
  }
}

function handleSignoutClick() {
  const token = gapi.client.getToken();
  if (token !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
    gapi.client.setToken("");
    content.innerText = "";
    sidebarHeading.style.visibility = "visible";
    signInBtn.innerText = "Sign In to Google Calendar";
    signOutBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    upcomingSearch.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

async function listUpcomingEvents(query = "") {
  let response;
  try {
    const request = {
      calendarId: "primary",
      timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
      timeMax: new Date(
        new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)
      ).toISOString(),
      showDeleted: false,
      singleEvents: true,
      maxResults: 10,
      orderBy: "startTime",
      q: query,
    };
    response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
  } catch (err) {
    content.innerText = err.message;
    return;
  }

  const events = response.result.items;
  if (!events || events.length == 0) {
    content.innerText = "No events found.";
    return;
  }

  const output = events.reduce(
    (str, event) =>
      `${str}${event.summary} (${event.start.dateTime || event.start.date})\n`,
    "Events:\n"
  );
  content.innerText = output;
}

function addEvents(events) {
  content.innerHTML = "";

  events.forEach((event) => {
    const eventInfo = document.createElement("p");
    eventInfo.textContent = `${event.summary} (${
      event.start.dateTime || event.start.date
    })`;
    content.appendChild(eventInfo);
  });
}

addEvents();

signInBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleAuthClick();
});

signOutBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleSignoutClick();
});

upcommingSearchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const upcomingQuery = document.getElementById("upcoming-query");
  const query = upcomingQuery.value;
  listUpcomingEvents(query);
});

apiConfig.onload = gapiLoaded();
clientConfig.onload = gisLoaded();


Here's my code so far for the server:
(app.js)

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const uniq = require("uniq");
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(uniq());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
  res.send();
});

app.use("/api/", router);

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Express is listening on http://localhost:8000...");
});


I have also installed Browserify and ESLint.
My issue is that I keep getting certain errors when I attempt to test my API setup on my calendar page. When I click the button that should prompt the Google sign-in popup, I get nothing on the page, and in the console, I get the following errors:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app.js:1:17
(anonymous) @   app.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at config.js:6:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'CLIENT_ID' has already been declared (at google-cal-config.js:1:1)

The last one especially confuses me, because I only declared 'CLIENT_ID' once.
These are errors that I had hoped ESLint would fix, but somehow, nothing is working. What's worse is that this is a project that's due tomorrow, and I really need to have my app working properly by then.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix all this? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Update: I've mostly figured out how to solve the original issue. Now, I do see changes on my page, yet the calendar still isn't showing, and now I'm getting 404 errors. The main reason has to relate to authorization this time.
Here is the updated code in question:

/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const content = document.getElementById("content");

const signInBtn = document.getElementById("authorize_button");
const signOutBtn = document.getElementById("signout_button");
const sidebarHeading = document.getElementById("sidebar-heading");
const upcomingSearch = document.getElementById("upcoming-search");
const upcommingSearchBtn = document.getElementById("upcoming-search-btn");

const apiConfig = document.getElementById("api-config");
const clientConfig = document.getElementById("client-config");

let tokenClient;
let gapiInited = false;
let gisInited = false;

function gapiLoaded() {
  gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient);
}

function initializeGapiClient() {
  gapi.client
    .init({
      apiKey: {my API key},
      clientId:
        {my client ID},
      discoveryDocs: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest",
      ],
      scope: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
      ],
    })
    .then(
      function () {
        gisLoaded();
      },
      function (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing Google API client:", error);
      }
    );
}

function gisLoaded() {
  tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id:
      {my client ID},
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    ],
    callback: "",
  });
  gisInited = true;
  maybeEnableButtons();
}

function maybeEnableButtons() {
  if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    document.getElementById("authorize_button").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

function getCalendarList() {
  gapi.client.calendar.calendarList
    .list()
    .then(function (response) {
      const calendars = response.result.items;
      calendars.forEach((calendar) => {
        console.log("Calendar ID:", calendar.id);
        console.log("Calendar Summary:", calendar.summary);
      });

      const primaryCalendarId = calendars.find(
        (c) => c.summary === "Primary"
      ).id;
      console.log("Primary Calendar ID:", primaryCalendarId);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching calendar list:", error);
    });
}

function handleAuthClick() {
  gapi.client.calendar.events
    .list({
      calendarId: "astringer92%40gmail.com",
      timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
      showDeleted: false,
      singleEvents: true,
      maxResults: 10,
      orderBy: "startTime",
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      const events = response.result.items;
      addEvents(events);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching events:", error);
    });
  sidebarHeading.style.visibility = "collapse";
  signInBtn.innerText = "Refresh";
  signOutBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  upcomingSearch.style.visibility = "visible";
  getCalendarList();
  listUpcomingEvents();

  if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" });
  } else {
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });
  }
}

function handleSignoutClick() {
  const token = gapi.client.getToken();
  if (token !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
    gapi.client.setToken("");
    content.innerText = "";
    sidebarHeading.style.visibility = "visible";
    signInBtn.innerText = "Sign In to Google Calendar";
    signOutBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    upcomingSearch.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  listUpcomingEvents();
}

async function listUpcomingEvents() {
  let response;
  try {
    const request = {
      calendarId: "astringer92@gmail.com",
      timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
      timeMax: new Date(
        new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)
      ).toISOString(),
      showDeleted: false,
      singleEvents: true,
      maxResults: 10,
      orderBy: "startTime",
    };
    response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(request);
  } catch (err) {
    content.innerText = err.message;
    return;
  }

  const events = response.result.items;
  if (!events || events.length == 0) {
    content.innerText = "No events found.";
    return;
  }

  const output = events.reduce(
    (str, event) =>
      `${str}${event.summary} (${event.start.dateTime || event.start.date})\n`,
    "Events:\n"
  );
  content.innerText = output;
}

function addEvents(events) {
  const content = document.getElementById("content");

  if (!events || !Array.isArray(events)) {
    content.innerHTML = "<p>No events found or invalid data.</p>";
    return;
  }

  content.innerHTML = "";

  events.forEach((event) => {
    const eventInfo = document.createElement("p");
    eventInfo.textContent = `${event.summary} (${
      event.start.dateTime || event.start.date
    })`;
    content.appendChild(eventInfo);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (apiConfig) {
    apiConfig.onload = gapiLoaded;
  } else {
    console.error("apiConfig element not found.");
  }

  if (clientConfig) {
    clientConfig.onload = gisLoaded;
  } else {
    console.error("clientConfig element not found.");
  }
});

signInBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleAuthClick();
});

signOutBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleSignoutClick();
});

upcommingSearchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const upcomingQuery = document.getElementById("upcoming-query");
  const query = upcomingQuery.value;
  listUpcomingEvents(query);
});

apiConfig.onload = gapiLoaded();
clientConfig.onload = gisLoaded();



Again, any help is appreciated. Thank you.
